# Mail function doesn't work for gmail

Tags: php, html, email

I'm creating php page and create button that post to php script. In my script, I create what normal mail functions need. I passed all the variables, it successfully sent. But my gmail didn't received any mail.

**sendmail.php**

```
<?php
$to = 'mygmail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from my page';

$headers = "To: email@hotmail.com\n" .
"From: From Address <from@mydomain.com>\n" .
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$message = 'TheMessage Body';
mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

$result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($result) {
    echo "MAIL SENT";
}else {
    echo 'MAIL NOT SENT';
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
 <form action="sendmail.php" method="POST" enctype="text/plain" id="contactForm">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
   <!-- if mail sent successfully  -->
     <h4 class="success">
       <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Your message has been sent successfully.
     </h4>
     <!-- if mail sent unsuccessfully  -->
     <h4 class="error">
       <i class="fa fa-warning"></i> E-mail must be valid and message must be longer than 1 character.
     </h4>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     <input  id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
     </div><!-- col-sm-6 end -->
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input  id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
     </div><!-- col-sm-6 end -->
     <div class="col-md-12">
       <textarea type="text" name="messages" class="textarea-box" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button class="btn-new btn-bold" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Submit Message</button>
      </div>                        
    </form>
```

Comment: Checkout your gmail's **spam** folder...

Comment: @FlowCastv have you checked the spam ??

Comment: Nothing in my spam folder...

Comment: Try sending without headers `mail("mygmail@gmail.com","My subject","Test EMail");` and which hosting server are you using?

Comment: @KamranAdil I'm using local server xampp

Comment: Might be you need to configure your server to send emails. Is it not going only to gmail?

Comment: You cannot send an email from local server using php `mail` function.Upload your code online and give it a try. It will work !!

Comment: Your mail works fine on godaddy server. Its the problem of your localhost that cannot send mails. Check their documentation to activate mail function.

Answer (score 0):

The email you are using on "From:" must exist in your server.
Another point, have you tried to send it a non-Gmail email account - does it arrive?

Comment: When you say successfully sent it means mail() function returned "true", right? But mail() return it's not fair enough to affirm if it was delivered or not, so don't pay attention to that pretty much. It means if it was accepted to be delivered according to php mail() function guidelines. But if the ISP is going to accept is another thing.